# Dropdowns aninhados não funcionam.Por quê?

Tags: html, dropdown

Tenho um dropdown dentro do outro. o primeiro funciona, ele abre o dropdown para a lista de itens.
Eu tentei colocar outro dropdown dentro dessa lista mas esse não funciona.Listar e conexao não funcionam.

```
<ul id="menu" class="nav nav-pills nav-justified  navbar-fixed-top">
<li role="presentation" class="active"><a
    href="index.php?pagina=inicio">inicio</a></li>
<li role="presentation" class="dropdown"><a href="dropdown-toggle"  data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Cadastro<span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li  role="presentation" class="dropdown"><a href="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" >Listar<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="index.php?pagina=alunos_listar">Alunos</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.php?pagina=responsaveis_listar">Responsáveis</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="index.php?pagina=responsaveis_cadastrar">Cadastro responsáveis</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?pagina=responsaveis_listar">Listar responsáveis</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?pagina=alunos_excluirFinally">Exluir cadastro do banco de dados</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="">Impressora</a></li>
<li role="presentation" class="dropdown"><a href="dropdown-toggle"  data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Opções<span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li  class="dropdown"><a href="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Conexão<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul  class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="index.php?Admin=Opcoes_conexao">Conexão</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="">Conexão</a></li>

<li role="presentation"><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
```

Na verdade o segundo dropdown eu queria que se comportasse como os menus de qualquer programa que vai abrindo abas para o lado. O primeiro dropdown seria para baixo e os outros para baixo e para o lado. Como no menu do windows.

Comment: Na verdade o segundo dropdown eu queria que se comportasse como os menus de qualquer programa que vai abrindo abas para o lado. O primeiro dropdown seria para baixo e os outros para baixo e para o lado. Como no menu do windows.

Comment: Como está o CSS?

Comment: neste caso estou usando o bootstrap puro mesmo com o "caret".

Comment: .caret {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 margin-left: 2px;
 vertical-align: middle;
 border-top: 4px dashed;
 border-top: 4px solid \9;
 border-right: 4px solid transparent;
 border-left: 4px solid transparent;
}

Comment: ele funciona só com um dropdown, o caret só faz o triangulo de indicação pelo que sei. o dropdown-menu que faz o movimento para baixo.

Comment: quero isso https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSHMzdLvBjklN5kZ3UIyg1Zr0xKyfg7LpjDhHyV0t_G2EjHk5DqzA

Comment: Há um erro de sintaxe, no fechamento da 1° `ul`,,,

Answer (score -3):

Esse exemplo abaixo, não te ajuda?

https://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_dropdown_multilevel_css&stacked=h

Atualizando, acho que esse link combina mais com o que você quer:

https://codepen.io/ajaypatelaj/pen/prHjD

Abaixo o exemplo do segundo link com o bootstrap:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">NavBar</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="https://github.com/fontenele/bootstrap-navbar-dropdowns" target="_blank">GitHub Project</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu 1 <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown</a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown</a>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu 2 <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown</a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown</a>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-template text-center">
        <h1>Bootstrap NavBar</h1>
        <p class="lead text-info">NavBar with too many childs.</p>
        <a target="_blank" href="http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/multi-level-dropdown-menu-bs3">Thanks to msurguy (Multi level dropdown menu BS3)</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Abaixo o CSS utilizado também no segundo link:

```
.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: -6px;
    margin-left: -1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-submenu>a:after {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    float: right;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    border-left-color: #ccc;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after {
    border-left-color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
    float: none;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu {
    left: -100%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
}
```

Comment: Esse link pode ser uma boa sugestão, mas sua resposta não terá validade se um dia o link deixar de funcionar. Além disso, é importante para a comunidade ter conteúdo aqui no site mesmo. Seria melhor incluir mais detalhes na sua resposta. Um resumo do conteúdo do link já ajudaria bastante! Saiba mais sobre o assunto neste item do nosso FAQ da Comunidade: [Queremos respostas que contenham somente links?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42/74)

Comment: isso que eu quero. vou estuda-lo agora. Contudo é interressante que não tenha funcionado no bootstrap. Digo, o aninhamento de dropdowns como fiz.

Comment: Ainda vou precisar aprender mais sobre esse recurso. pois até no exemplo do link ocorre um comportamento indesejado. Os dropdowns abertos não atualizam, isto é não voltam ao estado normal até que sejam clicados de novo ou a pagina atualize.  clicando fora do dropdown não o reinicia. Estranho.